# How to cut a .txt file in list view

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I wondered if there is a way to cut a .txt file in a one word per line view. I tried the following command:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' test.txt
```

this works only partially. I also tried 'awk' but had the same issues. To make sure you understand what I mean I give a little example of the text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

This is the output I want:

```
Lorem
Ipsum
is
simply
dummy
text
of
the
printing
and
typesetting
industry
```

Is it possible to do this with a simple command or does this take a little shell script?

Comment: You selected an answer that doesn't produce the output you asked for. Also consider how you want text like `it's` and `full-strength` and `27` and other quotation marks, etc. handled and then provide sample input and expected output for that. This is a non-trivial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
cat <yourfile> |  tr "\"' " '\n' > <newfile>
```

or

```
tr "\"' " '\n' < <yourfile> > <newfile>
```

With this, you are translating white spaces to new lines, and then forwarding the result into a new file.

Comment: Thanks, for the swift answer. Actually pretty but sometimes I do not see the wood for the trees.

Comment: UUOC: `tr "\"' " '\n' < <yourfile> > <newfile>`.

Comment: ^ Thank you, I totally forgot about that. :)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]' 'NF' file
Lorem
Ipsum
is
simply
dummy
text
of
the
printing
and
typesetting
industry
```

When looking at alternatives, notice which of them will correctly print `industry` instead of `industry.` (i.e. which handle punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tr`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/tr.html):

```
cat your.file | tr ' ' '\n'
```

The command will translate white spaces to new lines.

**Update** (Thanks @Ed Morten):

The cat command isn't required here. It can be replaced by input redirection:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < your.file
```

Comment: What's up with all the UUOCs in this thread? `tr " " "\n" < your.file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

Comment: `\n` will only work in some seds on some OSs. The portable way to use a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 1 RS=" " file
or
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS=" " file
or
awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n")}1' file
```